# Views Ajax Pager not working when loading view with ajax

Tags: views, ajax, javascript, paging

I have a page with a view that has a pager with ajax.
the pager is working fine when the page first run.

the page has a button that loads the next page using ajax, the view is loaded fine but the ajax pager is not working properly, just links without ajax (open pages directly).

how to make ajax pager work when loading a view via ajax, I'm using Drupal 7.28 with views 3.8

p.s. I think ajax view events needs to be rebinded to the pager links after loading the view through ajax, but I can't figure out how to achive that.

Comment: I m facing the same issue. If you found the solution please post it.